# Вопрос по оформлению функции Java

Tags: java

Имеется функция.

```
boolean isEqual(String str1, String str2) { 
...
return true;
}
```

Я не могу интегрировать ее в свою программу вида

```
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...    
  }
}
```

Куда мне засунуть эту функцию, чтобы программа работала? Варианты с переделыванием не рассматриваются, нужно использовать функцию в первоначальном виде.

Comment: добавить static или создавать экземпляр класса, в котором эта функция находится и вызывать через этот объект

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете либо объявить функцию в классе, потом в методе main создать экземпляр класса и у экземпляра класса вызывать эту функцию, либо сделать эту функцию статической и напрямую вызывать в методе main.

1)

```
class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
  hw.isEqual("str1", "str2");  
  }

  boolean isEqual(String str1, String str2) { 
     ...
  return true;
  }
}
```

2)

```
class HelloWorld {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      isEqual("str1", "str2");  
      }

      static boolean isEqual(String str1, String str2) { 
         ...
      return true;
      }
    }
```